# Spin of covariant derivatives in 3D $\mathcal{N}=2$ superspace

Tags: quantum-spin, differentiation, commutator, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers

Consider the 3D $\mathcal{N}=2$ superspace covariant derivatives $D_\alpha$ and $\bar D_\beta$, which have the following anti-commutation relations
$$\{ D_\alpha, \bar D_\beta \}=-2i \gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \partial_\mu$$
$$\{ D_\alpha, D_\beta \}=0$$
$$\{ \bar D_\alpha , \bar D_\beta \} = 0, $$
where $\alpha= 1,2$ and $\beta =1,2$ are spinor indices, and $\mu=1,2,3$ is the spacetime index.

I am doing a homework problem which asks me to construct differential operators using only these covariant derivatives  and find the highest possible spin for such differential operators.

What does it mean by the spin of differential operators? Does it mean just counting the spinor indices in the operator?

For example, $D_\alpha$ would have spin $\frac{1}{2}$, $D_\alpha \bar D_\beta$ would have spin 1, $D_\alpha \bar D_\beta D_\rho \bar D_\sigma D_\lambda$ would have spin $\frac{5}{2}$ and so on?

Comment: The symmetrization of $D_\alpha \bar{D}_\beta$ has spin 1 while its antisymmetrization has spin 0.

Comment: @ConnorBehan By smmetrisation do you mean $D_\alpha \bar D_\beta + D_\beta \bar D_\alpha$ has spin 1?

Comment: Yes. By choosing values for indices, you can check that 3 different results are possible. A spin $j$ irrep should have dimension $2j + 1$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this symmetrization/antisymmetrization procedure generalise to operators with larger number of covariant derivatives? For example, to examine the spin from $D_\alpha D_\beta \bar D_\rho $ I would have to look at the symmetrization $D_\alpha D_\beta \bar D_\rho + D_\beta D_\alpha \bar D_\rho + D_\beta D_\rho \bar D_\alpha + ... $?

Comment: This has nothing to do with covariant derivatives. It has to do with addition of angular momentum. When you couple many electrons that can each be spin up or down, there are various ways to symmetrize to get a total angular momentum eigenstate. A good QM textbook should explain how to tell which is which.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you very much for the discussion. I understand it now!